# Sublime: 1 file open as a row. Another file open in 2 columns

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I know you can change the entire layout to row, but is it possible to have one column open on one side and 2 rows open on another.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: VIEW>LAYOUT ....

Comment: ALT + Shift + 5 ..

Comment: View > Layout adds a column across both files. I want to try and a row only in between the file on the right

Comment: Then You Can Customized also ...

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/More%20Layouts   .. Check This

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Layout   Install it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open Sublime > Press : Ctrl + Shift + p**
and Then One Window Will Open At Top of Submlime., Where Type **install packages**
 it's suggest you. Click on it !! Then type : **layout** it's Suggest You !! 
Click On It !! It's Automatically Install it.

You Can View This : `View->Layout->`   And Which You want Its On `Alt + Shift + 7`.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/installation  --- Copy Package Python Code From Here ..